# PHPUnit. Теория написания тестов

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, phpunit

Допустим, есть класс. С двумя методами.

```
    function getId($string) {
        /*Проверяем строку на валидность и если все окей, пишем ее в свойство класса*/
        $this->id = $string;
    }
    function buildUrl() {
        /*Проверяем наличие свойства и строим URL для доступа к чему-то там...*/
        if ($this->id) {/*бла-бла-бла*/}
    }
```

Теперь вопрос. При покрытии тестами, что я должен передавать методам? То, что они ожидают принять в идеале? То есть, валидную строку в первом случае и непустое свойство во втором.

Или то, что они не ожидают? Всякую невалидную чушь в первом случае и отсутствие свойства во втором.

Или два теста, один на ожидаемые параметры, а второй на неожиданные?

P.S. Только разбираюсь с тестированием, так что в матчасти не силен.

P.P.S. Если это важно, то в случае успеха методы выдают `true`, а в случае неудачи - выбрасывают `Exception`. Поскольку, при неправильных параметрах продолжать выполнение скрипта не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тесты должны покрывать функциональность модуля в различных типичных сценариях, и позитивных, и негативных. Методы класса должны возвращать ожидаемые значения, или ожидаемым образом реагировать при передаче неправильных типов на вход, например, выбрасывать  ожидаемые  исключения.
Вы привели довольно простой пример, там можно придумать не так и много сценариев для тестирования. Но в более сложных ситуациях, вы должны предусмотреть и менее очевидные варианы. К примеру, передачу в метод аргумента правильного типа, но не верно сконфигурированного. Тесты должны покрывать большинство ветвлений исполнения программы, чем важнее модуль, тем более полным должно быть покрытие. Также стоит покрывать тестами типичные  сценарии  взаимодействия с другими модулями системы. Такие IDE как PhpStorm отлично помогают ориентироваться в том, какие места кода не покрыты тестами. Позже, с каждым обнаруженным и исправленным багом, дописывайте тест, который будет отлавливать такие ошибки. Плюс при написании тестов отлично всплывают все зависимости  модулей друг от друга, так что тесты скорее всего полтолкнуи васк рефакторингу отдельных модулей и помогут более правильно проектировать свои классы. Плохо спроектированные классы почти всегда трудно покрыть нормальными тестами, не протащив с собой в тесты простыню из лишних зависимостей.

**UPD. Пример для вашего класса**

```
// $this->aClass - содержит экземпляр вашего класса

public function testGetById() {
    $this->assertTrue($this->aClass->getById('validString'));
}

/**
*@expectedException Exception
*/
public function testGetByIdThrowsException() {
    $this->aClass->getById(null);
}

public function testBuildUrl() {
    $this->aClass->getById('string');
    $this->assertTrue($this->aClass->buildUrl());
}

/**
*@expectedException Exception
*/
public function testBuildUrlThrowsException() {
    $this->aClass->buildUrl();
}
```

Обратите внимание на аннотации `@expectedException`.
Подробнее можно прочитать здесь: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions

Опять же, учитывая, что пример простой, то и тесты не особо интересные.

Comment: Ну это я понимаю. Но вот как именно написать тест для данных функций? То есть, передаем верный параметр и проверяем вывод, затем неверный и проверяем вывод и так далее? Просто все примеры, которые мне попадались - это "Давайте проверим, как функция умножает два на два", а я хочу разобраться на реальном примере, пусть и простеньком.

Comment: добавил пример для вашего класса

Comment: О, вот за это огромное спасибо. возьму как шаблончик. Изучать)